# Solenoid valve gating and time proportional control

Tags: control, pid-controller, hvac

I'm trying to complete this simple task:
I have solenoid valves to control the humidity in an array of boxes. I use time proportional PID control to turn them on or off. I suspect I keep wearing them down because I am switching them too fast. Here is the basic code in the main loop:

```
PID.Compute(); //compute output (0-3000ms). WINDOW_SIZE = 3000 ms.
if (millis() - start_time> WINDOW_SIZE) start_time = millis(); //shift window
//the above part is fine and I leave unchanged. have been tinkering with the below.
if (output < millis() - start_time) digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH);
else digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
```

[*Link to PID library with example.*](https://github.com/br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library/blob/master/examples/PID_RelayOutput/PID_RelayOutput.ino)

I want to make it so that a change of state can happen no faster than every 500ms. I have tried multiple ideas now, all failing. Valves behave erratically, either never staying completely open even when PID output is at constant max, or flicking on and off within 100ms. Does someone have some code they know will work? My project team is looking at me funny, like "this was supposed to be done yesterday". Not my forte.

I've tried the following:

-Right after PID output is computed, I change outputs >2500 to 3000 and outputs <500 to 0. This doesn't work.

```
if (rh_output > WINDOW_SIZE-MIN_WINDOW) rh_output = WINDOW_SIZE; //quickest change 0.5s
else if (rh_output <= MIN_WINDOW) rh_output = 0; //quickest change 0.5s
```

-I have a separate timer keeping track of the last time a switch happened.

```
  if (rh_output <= millis() - rh_start) {
    if (digitalRead(SOLENOID_VALVE_RELAY_PIN) == HIGH && millis() - last_change >= MIN_CHANGE_TIME) {
      digitalWrite(SOLENOID_VALVE_RELAY_PIN, !HIGH); //window off time (INVERTED LOGIC SOLENOID VS SSR)
      last_change = millis(); // Update the time of the last change
    }
  }
  else {
    if (digitalRead(SOLENOID_VALVE_RELAY_PIN) == LOW && millis() - last_change >= MIN_CHANGE_TIME) {
      digitalWrite(SOLENOID_VALVE_RELAY_PIN, !LOW); //window off time (INVERTED LOGIC SOLENOID VS SSR)
      last_change = millis(); // Update the time of the last change
    }
  }
```

-I have tried using a button debouncing library, but that doesn't quite do it.
-I have considered changing the parameters of the PID object to return output from 500-3000, and turn 500 outputs to 0 manually. Does not seem like the way to go.
-I have considered attaching an interrupt to the relay pin.

Thank you in advance. Regards.

[image]

Comment: "I suspect I keep wearing them down because I am switching them too fast." What makes you think that? Generally they like fast PWM, though admittedly most of my experience is from hydraulic valves, not pneumatic. Do you have parts failing? The reason might be something else entirely.

Comment: As for tweaking your PID regulator, that's best done by dumping all values in some sort of log like on UART. Import to excel and let it draw graphs. How is the calculated curve doing in comparison with the actual curve? When looking at it visually like that, it is often easier to know which PID parameter to tweak. Is it oscillating, does it have large overshoot etc.

Comment: And finally for the love of your own sanity, pick a MCU with a built-in PWM hardware peripheral. Doing this manually with some Arduino library software timers based on some free-running timer is both painful and unprofessional.

Comment: @Lundin I am unaware of MCU's where I can specify the PWM period to be 3 seconds. PWM is specifically what I am avoiding here, as I am switching an audible physical contact on and off rapidly, not a silent transistor. Besides volume, wear-and-tear really is a concern.

Comment: So these are not proportional solenoids but on/off?

Comment: @Lundin correct, on/off

Comment: You don't need to use hardware for slow PWM. Just generate periodic interrupts and do the count, on/off comparison and output toggle in the ISR. 1% resolution is probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the output as a time-proportioning on/off output with a cycle time as long as you want, particularly if you sample the continuous controller output at the end of each cycle.

For example, if the controller is calling for 20% you might have the valve on for 20 seconds and off for 80 seconds. The limit to how long the cycle can be is how much ripple you can tolerate in the actual humidity.

For humidity, I would think that a cycle time in the minutes would be appropriate.

If you are getting changes in the measured PV that are not realistic (due to the sensor getting wet or something like that) you may have to do more than that in order to estimate the actual humidity reasonably accurately.

Comment: In my case, i need oscillations to be very small, and the box volume is very small, and the humidity actuator is fast-acting. 

I am wondering if PID.compute() should be run once every window, as opposed to once every loop, as this changes output many times before one window is complete...

Comment: There is no point in running it faster. Slower means you'll be able to measure derivative (if you're using it- often it doesn't help at all) better.

Comment: Thank you for the help